# Unexpected value 'InlineEditorModule' imported by the module

Tags: angular, inline-editing, inlineeditbox

Anybody had this problem?

Unexpected value 'InlineEditorModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'.
in my app.module.ts:

```
import { InlineEditorModule } from 'ng2-inline-editor';

...
@NgModule({
imports: [InlineEditorModule, ...],
declarations: [...]
`

in my template:

    <inline-editor type="text" [(ngModel)]="editableText" (onSave)="saveEditable($event)" name="editableText1" size="8"></inline-editor>
```

I installed using npm:

```
npm i ng2-inline-editor --save
```

Did I miss anything?

I followed below URL content

https://github.com/Caballerog/ng2-inline-editor

Comment: did you reference the module from systemjs.config.js?

Comment: are you using angular 4.0 or 2?

Comment: @suraj: I am using angular 2

Comment: @pixelbits: I am using  webpack (not systemjs.config.js) which is generated by jHipster generated angular2 project.

Comment: @RamaKrishna according to one of the examples in your github [link](https://github.com/Caballerog/ng2-inline-editor/blob/master/demos/basic/package.json#L24) you could probably work with an older version `^0.1.1-alpha.11`

Comment: @Suraj I tried with ^0.1.1-alpha.11  but same result

Comment: use **0.1.1-alpha.12** is the latest stable version for Angular 2, after that, all are for angular 4.